# mvc3 dapper No mapping exists from model

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, dapper

I am doing some coding in dapper and I get the error **No mapping exists from object type  to a known managed provider native type** this error occurs on the **myfriends** var for dapper . I am using dapper to get a list of INT values from a table then comparing them against another.. this is the code that gives me that error

```
   int myid = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
 // The var myfriend is giving me that error above
            var myfriends = sqlConnection.Query<friend>("Select otherfriendsID from friends where profileID=@myidd", new { myidd = myid }).ToList();

            var profiles = sqlConnection.Query<profile>("Select top 40 * from profiles where photo is not null AND profileID=@friendship order by profileID desc", new {friendship=myfriends}).ToList();
```

however if I use entity everything works fine for instance this code below works..

```
            var myfriends = (from s in db.friends where s.profileID == myid select s.otherfriendsID).ToList();
```

What could be going on here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myfriends` is a `List<friend>`. You then pass that in as a query parameter, i.e.

```
new {friendship=myfriends}
```

with:

```
AND profileID=@friendship
```

Now... what is `@friendship` ? How should it pass in a `List<friend>` here? What does that even *mean* to pass in a list of objects (each of which could have multiple properties) as a single parameter? (note: I'm ignoring table-valued-parameters for the purposes of this question)

So: how many `myfriends` do you expect? 0? 1? any number? This could be, for example:

```
var profileIds = myfriends.Select(x => x.ProfileId);
...
new {profileIds}
...
AND profileID in @profileIds
```

or maybe:

```
new {profileId = myfriends.Single().ProfileId}
...
AND profileID = @profileId
```

Comment: myfriends will have about a list of 20-50 people and thanks alot  the var profileIds = myfriends.Select(x => x.ProfileId) worked perfectly; in your experience do you think that Dapper used in this manner would be faster than Entity in regards to having to scan a database table with lots of records ?

Comment: @user that depends on the query used, the library used, and the techniques used: but basically, "yes I think that will be just about as fast as it can be"